# How to require a json file using dynamic file path

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, dynamic

Does any body know how to use a dynamic path for importing json file in javascript with laravel?

```
var json_file = require('D:\\WS1\\my-app\\public\\locale\\pt_PT\\LC_MESSAGES\\javascript.json');
```

I want something like

```
var lang;
var jsonToLoad;
var json file = require(root_path()+'/public/locale'+lang+'/LC_MESSAGES/'+jsonToLoad);
```

Comment: Are you using webpack? Is this on the client side (browser) or in the backend (Node.js)?

Comment: How are you wanting to use Laravel for this?

Comment: @PatrickHund and yes I'm using a  webpack, I want to make a library. The locale folder is inside the public, Im using some library installed by node

Comment: @Rwd Im making a small library that needs to fetch a json file from the public folder